# Java Skips over "While" loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Forgive me if this is something stupid, as I am relatively new at Java

The current program compiles, however it completely skips the while loop.

```
  //Defined Variables
  static boolean breaker  = false;
  static boolean breaker2 = false;
  static boolean tf       = false;
  static boolean tf2      = false;
  static int     code     = 0;
  static int     random   = -8;
  static String  input    = "Nothing here"; 

  System.out.println("1");

  //Resetting variables to control while loop
  breaker = false;
  tf = true;

  random = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);  

  while(breaker2 = false)
  {
     input = i.nextLine();

     if (random >= 90)
     tf = false;

     if (input.equals("N") || input.equals("n"))
     {
        System.exit(0);
     }
     else
     {
        if (input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y"))
        {
           tf2 = false;
           breaker2 = true;
        }
           else
           {
              //Text output
           }        
     }
  }
     System.out.println("3");
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

Everything is executed except the while loop. I have had trouble before with this, and wrote the loop from scratch. It had the same issues. 
("1" "2" and "3" are used to mark what was executed.)

Comment: `while(breaker2 = false)` should be `while(breaker2 == false)` or `while(!breaker2)`

Answer (score 3):

This is because of

```
while(breaker2 = false)
```

You are assigning the value of `breaker2` to false, meaning you will never enter this loop.

Use either

```
while ( breaker == false )
// or
while ( !breaker )
```

Answer (score 1):

In a condition you need two `==`

```
breaker2 = false
```

this assigns breaker2 to false

```
breaker2 == false
```

this returns true if breaker2 is equal to false.

You could also do

```
while(!breaker2)
```

If breaker2 equals false it is flipped to true with the ! symbol